# How to apply scraping function to an entire column in a dataframe

Tags: python, web-scraping

this will be a long post as the problem I'm facing is embedded in a larger project -- thanks to anyone who takes the time to read this.

Basically, I'm scraping the Wikipedia:Featured articles page. There are hundreds of article links on this page and I have already succeeded in compiling a list of articles from this page that are biographies. The following codes were used:

```
def __api_GET_latest_page(title):
parameters = {
    "action": "parse",
    "page": title,
    "format": "json"
}
response_json = __get("revisions", title, parameters)
if("parse" in response_json.keys() 
    and "text" in response_json["parse"].keys() 
    and "*" in response_json["parse"]["text"].keys()):
    return response_json["parse"]["text"]["*"]
return None

def __get(function_key, key, parameters, check_cache=True, write_cache=True):
target = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php"
cache_path = "cached_api"
params_unicode = str(parameters).encode('utf-8')
md5 = hashlib.md5(params_unicode).hexdigest()
return_json = None

cache_file = os.path.join(cache_path, function_key, str(key), md5)
cache_exists = os.path.isfile(cache_file)
if cache_exists:
    try:
        json_in = open(cache_file, "r")
        json_str = json_in.read()
        return_json = json.loads(json_str)
        if "error" in return_json.keys() and "code" in return_json["error"].keys() and return_json["error"]["code"]=="maxlag":
            cache_exists = False
    except:
        cache_exists = False

if not cache_exists:
    cache_dir = os.path.dirname(cache_file)
    if not os.path.isdir(cache_dir):
        os.makedirs(cache_dir)
    r = requests.get(target, params=parameters)
    request_json = r.json()
    json_out = open(cache_file, "w")
    print(json.dumps(request_json), file=json_out)
    return_json = request_json
return return_json

def __remove_tables_and_scripts(tree):
tags_to_remove = ["tbody", "td", "script"]
for tag in tags_to_remove:
    elements = tree.find(f".//{tag}")
    if elements is not None:
        for e in elements:
            e.getparent().remove(e)
return tree

def page_text(name, format, include_tables = False):
try:
    result = __api_GET_latest_page(name)
except:
    print("API request failed.")
if result:
    e = etree.fromstring(result)
    if not include_tables:
        e = __remove_tables_and_scripts(e)
    if format == "html":
        return str(etree.tostring(e))
    elif format == "text":
        return ''.join(e.itertext())
    elif format == "list":
        return ''.join(e.itertext()).split('\n')
else:
    print("Failed to retrieve a page.")
    return None
```

The above code, specifically the ​page_text() function, gets the plain text of any Wikipedia page and caches the result locally. Anyways, with the following code, I got a list of all the article titles in the wikipedia featured articles page which are biographies:

```
def get_featured_biographies(t):  
titles = page_text("Wikipedia:Featured articles", "list")

titles = titles[40: ]

titles = titles[:-7]

titles = list(filter(lambda x: x != '', titles))

list_featured_biographies = []

boolean = False 
for elem in t:
    if ('[edit]' in elem) and ('biographies' in elem) | ('Biographies' in elem):
        boolean = True 
        continue
    elif ('[edit]' in elem) and ('biographies' not in elem):
        boolean = False

    if boolean:
        list_featured_biographies = list_featured_biographies + [elem]
    else:
        continue 

return list_featured_biographies 

list_featured_biographies = get_featured_biographies(titles)
```

This is an example of the output:

[image: list output example]

Here's where I run into problems. I need to write a function that scrapes all of the individual pages for featured article biography titles in the list I created created. Specifically, I need to write a function that extracts the first paragraph of each biography. I have succeeded in this task with the following code:

```
for title in list_featured_biographies:
page_content = page_text(title, "list")

list_of_values_with_keywords = []
for value in page_content:

    if ('was a' in value) | ('was an ' in value) | ('is a ' in value) | ('is an ' in value):
        list_of_values_with_keywords.append(value)

first_paragraph = list_of_values_with_keywords[0]

print(first_paragraph)
```

And so Bronwyn Bancroft, Felice Beato, and Jean Bellette are the first three names. The following screenshot shows the output for these first three names.

[image: output example for first three biographies]

As you can see, my output is essentially a list of first paragraphs. **I would like to organize this information into a two column dataframe, with the first column being the name of the article title and the second being the article's first paragraph.** The following code encounters an error in trying to achieve this:

```
title2_list = []
list_of_first_para = []

for title in list_featured_biographies:
page_content = page_text(title, "list")

title2_list.append(title)

list_of_values_with_keywords = []
for value in page_content:

    if ('was a' in value) | ('was an ' in value) | ('is a ' in value) | ('is an ' in value):
        list_of_values_with_keywords.append(value)

first_paragraph = list_of_values_with_keywords[0]

list_of_first_para.append(first_paragraph)

data2_for_df = {'Article_Title':title2_list, 'First_Paragraph':list_of_first_para}

wiki1para_df = pd.DataFrame(data2_for_df)

print(wiki1para_df)
```

This is the error I run into:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-317-f36585876409> in <module>
     13     return first_paragraph
     14 
     16 print(first_paragraph)
<ipython-input-317-f36585876409> in get_first_paragraph(list)
      9                 list_of_values_with_keywords.append(value)
    10 
---> 11         first_paragraph = list_of_values_with_keywords[0]
     12 
    13     return first_paragraph
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: "scraping", not "scrapping". "Scrapping" implies "throwing in the trash".

Comment: Thanks a lot -- my bad.

Comment: Edit the *full* text of the error message into your question.

Comment: Okay. What I've edited in is the full error message.